# What would be the most efficient way to SELECT, then DELETE this immediately

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the most efficient way to SELECT this, then DELETE it immediately.

```
SELECT * from `usersOnline` WHERE timestamp>NOW()-INTERVAL 5 SECOND ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

How could I take this same select query, but also make it delete what it selected in the most efficient way?

Comment: related: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=158486

Comment: Is it you want to delete the results of the query from the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `usersOnline` WHERE timestamp>NOW()-INTERVAL 5 SECOND ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$query = 'DELETE FROM `usersOnline` WHERE id = ' . $record['id'];
mysql_query($query);
```

with mysql, you would have to do one and then the other. you would use the key from the select result to then delete that record directly afterwards. in this example, i am assuming your primary key column is named "id". you would replace the myssql functions with whichever method you are using to access the database of course.

Comment: simple enough. That's what I was going to do. But I thought there might have just been 1 query way to do it or something I wasn't aware of. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this nested query

```
DELETE  
FROM SomeTable  
WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT * from `usersOnline` WHERE timestamp>NOW()-INTERVAL 5 SECOND ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
)
```

thanks

Comment: i believe he wants to both select to get the results as well as delete them.

Answer (score 0):

use DELETE FROM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: i believe he wants to both select to get the results as well as delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this example mixed prepared statments with regular statements. But it's up to the developer how to write the code. This is just a proof of concept, kept simple for easy reading.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'userTable');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from `usersOnline` WHERE timestamp>NOW()-INTERVAL 5 SECOND ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM 'usersOnline WHERE id = ?");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $row["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: If `id` is the only required field why use `select *`

Comment: Because it seems the OP wants to use the user data. This way, inside the while loop, extra code can be used to process the data as needed.